# Rotation of a tree so it becomes an AVL tree

Tags: tree, rotation, avl-tree

Who can help me to rotate the following tree so it becomes an AVL tree?
[image]

Previous steps were these
[image]

Comment: @StefanFreitag look at the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, this is the solution
[image]

I used the following image to understand it
[image]